# Search Multiple Block of data

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I have a set of data nearly 2000+ rows (see Image 1 for sample). Need to ensure every product type has a **Start of Day** row. If this is missing, flag it.

Either the block that is missing the start of balance has to be highlighted OR transferred to a different sheet within the same work book.

- I have tried to use the subtotal function to see if it could help (couldn't get my head around it). for every change in product type, count product type that gives me the number of rows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just every distinct Product Type, or every distinct ProductType+Region ?

Comment: Hi Tim, every distinct product type+region should have a 'Start of Day'

Answer (score 1):

You can use an additional column with a formula for this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your replying so quickly, How do I tweak the formula if I want the result only on product type instead?

Comment: Remove the first two arguments from the formula `=COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C, "Start of day") > 0`

Comment: thats brilliant! i have been complicating it with if & for loops. Thanks a lot again!